# Should I use CSS filters as it has the Working Draft status

Tags: html, css, browser, css-filters

[image]

CSS filters are kinda supported by most browsers.
But as it has the Working Draft status, is it recommended to use it? (in production)

Comment: That's very much a matter of opinion (and thus off-topic).

Comment: The W3C documents will tell you not to use WD features in production as they are subject to breaking changes. But if you're going to follow W3C's advice, you're going to forgo a very large amount of features that range from not implemented in any browser at all, to widely and interoperably implemented over the last 5 years. This is not necessarily a bad thing if you value truly interoperable CSS and don't want to leave any browser in the dust, but it's something to keep in mind.

Comment: Thank you very much @BoltClock 

Comment: @BoltClock Can you please provide the link where it tell use not to use WD features in production?

Comment: @dman: Every WD contains a Status section beginning with a paragraph that goes out of its way to discourage you from using draft features in production and expecting stable behavior. For example, [here's the one for selectors-4](https://www.w3.org/TR/2018/WD-selectors-4-20181121/#status).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see on your picture of the website [caniuse](https://caniuse.com), if you do not need your website to get this functionnality on Opera Mini & IE, you can use it.

As most used browsers (Firefox, Chrome, Safari) set up this proprety, you can take it for granted.